# VB6 SetWindowText

Tags: vb6

I have several different user controls that get built dynamically and added to a tab user control that ultimately sits on a form in VB6.

What I would like to do is whenever a tab is the active tab I would like to change the Title text to the form to the text of the tab.

I'm looking at the the `SetWindowText` API, but I'm not sure where to put it.  Do I put it on the form?  Do I put it in the Tab user control or the individual user controls.

If there is something other then `SetWindowText` that I should use, please let me know.

Comment: Do you own this form? That is, is it created by your application? If so, Chris's solution seems like the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
Me.Caption = TabStrip1.SelectedItem.Caption
```

Comment: I do own the form as it has a reference to the user control with the tabs on it.  However, I can't seem to reference the usercontrol.tabstrip to get the selectedItem...

Comment: If you do own the usercontrol with the tabs add a public property `SelectedItemCaption`